# Finding the centre of mass? What axis does the centre of mass lie on?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let the mass density $\mu$ be given by
$$\mu(x,y,z)=
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} \leq1$$

what axis would the centre of mass lie on?

Comment: Use latex http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php to write maths here, putting the writing inside of dollar signs.

Comment: Do you mean $\min\{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{a^2},1\}$?

Comment: Thankyou @HagenvonEitzen I am new to this forum and i am working on my formatting.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Is there a link i can use that explains how to write everything in that format?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that  $\mu(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}$ when the inequality is satisfied, and $\mu(x,y,z)=0$ elsewhere,$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} \le 1$$ Describes an ellipsoid. By symmetry, the centre of mass must lie on the $x$ $y$ and $z$ axes (thus lies in the centre).

(By 'symmetry', I mean that (considering the $z$- axis), for each mass element $m_i$ at $\mathbf{r_i}=(x,y,z_0)$, there is a mass element $m_j$ at $\mathbf{r_j}=(-x,-y,-z_0)$ that cancels, as, plugging the co-ordinates into $\mu$, $m_i=m_j$, and so $m_i \mathbf{r_i}+m_j \mathbf{r_j}=0$).

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your original (unedited) question. Did you mean the body ellipsoidal, but with an arbitrary density function?

Comment: Hi @Alyosha as the question is showing now is exactly how I am intending it to be. So would the integral just be '0'? Or do i integrate the μ function with the dot product of an axis?

Comment: I just your edited version after I posted my last question. Ok, so the integral would be 0. Thankyou for your help Alyosha :)

Comment: $\int \mu(\mathbf{s})(\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{r}_{COM})d \mathbf{s}$ would be zero, of course, not $\int \mu(\mathbf{s}) d \mathbf{s}$ (which $=0$).